# Regular Expression validation of a property in a model

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am trying to validate a property which must have nine-digit code and cannot end with four zeros or four nines and must be entered without special characters.

I tried the following code-

```
[RegularExpression(@"(^(?i:([a-z])(?!\1{2,}))*$)|(^[A-Ya-y1-8]*$)", ErrorMessage = "You can not have that")]
public string Test{ get; set; }
```

But it's not working.

**Example:** `exasdea0000`,`asdea9999`,`exasde@0000` or `as_ea9999` can't be inputted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you have sample input or test cases?

Comment: what are special characters to you? what's formatting?

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/rIU0aJ/1) help?

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. "It's not working" isn't a proper problem description.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your regex like this:

```
^(?!\d+[09]{4}$)\d{9}$
```

Explanation:

```
^                   // from start point
 (?!                // look forward to don't have
    .+              // some characters
    [09]{4}         // followed by four chars of 0 or 9
    $               // and finished
 )
 \d{9}              // nine characters of digits only
$                   // finished
```

[`[Regex Demo]`](https://regex101.com/r/14uMLe/1)